# How to see the PostgreSQL VIEW object definition in datagrip?

Tags: datagrip

When I select the View object and press "Ctrl +Q" (On Menu >> Click "View" >> Click "Quick Documentaion"), it does works for MS SQL server but not for PostgreSQL View object.

For Microsoft SQL Server, it shows correctly:

```
Definition:
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[StudentsView]
AS
SELECT Id, UserName, FullName, CreateDate
FROM            dbo.Student
```

For PostgreSQL, It shows only upto view name and AS keyword.

```
Definition:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW employee.managers_vw AS
```

Is there a way to see the PostgreSQL VIEW object definition in datagrip?

Comment: Please try to invoke *Synchronize* action for the PostgreSQL data source and then View | Quick Documentation.

Comment: Synchronize did not help @Andrey Thanks.

Comment: Can you file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE with the actual DDL for the view and results of *Test Connection* output for Postgres data source? We will check it. Thanks.

Comment: What about DDL tab in Table Viewer? The same?

Comment: @moscas For tables, DDL works. Thanks

Comment: I mean — double click on view and then DDL tab like here — https://twitter.com/0xdbe/status/724602466969497601

Comment: I took 2016.1 update and get the message on DDL tab "-- definition is not available or empty"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone still looking for this answer:

1. Right-Click the View in the Database window
2. Select Open DDL in Console shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: that shortcut isn't working on mac. what is shortcut for Mac ??

Comment: Ctrl + B worked for me (Ubuntu) instead of Shift + F4